# Jitterbit export to csv with header

Tags: csv, header, jitterbit

Using Jitterbit studio 8.26.1.2.
Trying to transfer data from db to csv. It works but the csv file does not have headers. Would like to have header with names as in the source table.

would like:
id,fname,lname
1,John,Smith
2,Theresa Map

instead:
1,John,Smith
2,Theresa Map

What is the easiest way to achieve this?
[simple operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4zin.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this in your Local File target, but checking the "Write Headers" box, in the options section.

Documents are here: https://success.jitterbit.com/display/DOC/Creating+a+Local+File+Target